# How to iterate org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource Object

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf

I have managed to parse the XML file and create the resource object using EMF Modelling, How do I retrieve the data's from the XML file ?
Attached the Ecore Model.
[image: Parsing method]
[image: Ecore]

Answer (score 0):

```
resource.getContents()
```

to retrieve the list of root semantic elements in the resource.
Usually there is only 1.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I'm using the EMF for the first time I have tried JAXB for the XML parsing, so if I want to get the value for "BarStyleColor" how it would be?

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know your metamodel (.ecore file) and your model, or the factory you are using. Are you sure your model is an EMF model in the first place? In any case you can refer to this tutorial: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEMFPersistence/article.html#load-an-existing-model

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your scenario you may also use getAllContents() which returns a TreeIterator. It might be useful if you want to, say, iterate over all instances of a particular type.